# build ionic 3 app for production failed and i'm not understand why?

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, npm

when i build my ***ionic v3*** app for *production* using this command :

> ionic cordova build android --prod --release

*it failed give this error*

```
[02:27:35]  ngc started ... 
[02:27:40]  ionic-app-script task: "build" 
[02:27:40]  RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded 
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at StaticReflector.annotations (/home/nazeeh/Desktop/ionic Projects/Aromix/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:30412:14)
    at NgModuleResolver.resolve (/home/nazeeh/Desktop/ionic Projects/Aromix/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:20105:70)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (/home/nazeeh/Desktop/ionic Projects/Aromix/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:15101:60)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleSummary (/home/nazeeh/Desktop/ionic Projects/Aromix/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:15042:52)
    at /home/nazeeh/Desktop/ionic Projects/Aromix/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:15149:68
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (/home/nazeeh/Desktop/ionic Projects/Aromix/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:15144:49)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleSummary (/home/nazeeh/Desktop/ionic Projects/Aromix/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:15042:52)
    at /home/nazeeh/Desktop/ionic Projects/Aromix/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:15149:68
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! ionicEcommerce@0.0.1 ionic:build: `ionic-app-scripts  build "--prod" "--target" "cordova" "--platform" "android"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the ionicEcommerce@0.0.1 ionic:build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/nazeeh/.npm/_logs/2020-02-26T00_27_40_834Z-debug.log
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess npm.

        npm run ionic:build -- --prod --target cordova --platform android exited
        with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more
        information.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the ERROR in Maximum call stack size exceeded happens actually when you have some infinite loop in your code.vérify the load of your module or maybe the call of your methode

Comment: when i debug the app no error found all functions work well .
no infinite loop happen.